# Функция gets() небезопасна?

Tags: c++

Всем привет! Вот, собственно, вопрос про С++ : простенькое считывание строки с помощью функции gets() вызывает предупреждение : мол, небезопасно. Почему так?
И второй вопрос вдогонку - почему программа корректно работает, ведь я не включил заголовок , который нужен функции gets()?
Всем спасибо!
[image: Предупреждение]
[image: Функция gets]

Comment: Про это даже в [вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gets#.D0.91.D0.B5.D0.B7.D0.BE.D0.BF.D0.B0.D1.81.D0.BD.D0.BE.D1.81.D1.82.D1.8C_.D0.B8.D1.81.D0.BF.D0.BE.D0.BB.D1.8C.D0.B7.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.8F) написано, не говоря уж о более специализированных ресурсах... Лень вперёд вас родилась?

Comment: В программе есть ошибка, в слове "считываение".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том, что `gets()` читает все до символа `'\n'` или конца файла, невзирая на размер. Вы выделили 100 байт, введено 200 - куда лишние 100 байт будут записаны? поверх чего-то в стеке. Чем и пользуются всякие злокозненные хакеры,  подставляя ввод такой, что он перезаписывает что надо где надо и делает в результате то, что надо хакеру...

Ну, значит, у вас `<iostream>` опосредованно включает нужный заголовок...

Answer (score 1):

Функция `gets` не контролирует размер вводимых данных в символьный массив, а потому она может записать данные за пределы символьного массива.

Функция `gets` больше не поддерживается стандартом языка C. Вместо нее используйте функцию `fgets`. Например, для вашей программы вызов фцнкции может выглядеть следующим образом

```
fgrts( str, sizeof( str ), stdin );
```

Эта функция также заносит в символьный массив символ новой строки, если для него в массиве есть место. В большинстве случаев его следует удалить из символьного массива, так как он не нужен. В C++ это можно сделать следующими способами

```
#include <cstring>

//...

fgrts( str, sizeof( str ), stdin );

str[ std::strcspn( str, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
```

Или

```
if ( ( char *p = std::strchr( str, '\n' ) ) *p = '\0';
```

В С++ лучше использовать стандартные C++ функции для ввода данных в символьный массив, как, например, функцию-член класса `getline`. Например,

```
std::sin.getline( str, sizeof( str ) );
```

В общем случае если вы работаете со стандартными функциями ввода-вывода C, то следует явно включать заголовок `<cstdio>`. В отношении вашей программы, видимо, заголовочный файл `<iostream>`  сам включил этот заголовок C в вашу программу.